# JavaFX 2.2 Remove Pagination's selected page label

Tags: java, css, pagination, javafx-2

I want to remove the *Selected page label* (see image below) of the [Pagination](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Pagination.html) control.

After digging into caspian.css I wasn't able to find any clue about how to do that. By code I also didn't find any method to remove (or eventually hide) this label.

Is there a way to do that in JavaFX without re-implementing the whole control ?

[image: Pagination navigation]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `-fx-page-information-visible`

It's described within these links:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/pagination.htm
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/pagination.htm#JFXUI459
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#pagination

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way either to hide just the label, but would it help to hide the whole button?

```
.number-button:selected{
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

That would hide the current selected button.
It's not what you actually wanted but maybe it can help you.